# using let operator for Intervals in linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

please consider this image:

[image]

I have a table like this:

```
 Age              Active            Men/Women
 -------------------------------------------------
```

I want to write a query with linq to entities that calulate `Count` of every age intervals for men and women. I canusing `let` operator to calculate single row but I want to calculat All in one query.

thanks

Comment: Can you manually produce the result you are going for for this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think this is possible in Linq2Sql, but I came up with this Query:

```
Func<int, string> ageGroup = age => string.Format("Age {0}-{1}", (age / 5) * 5, ((age / 5) * 5) + 4);
var blub = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
           where row.IsActive == 1
           group row by ageGroup(row.age)
           into grouped
           from g in grouped
           let menCount = g.Aggregate(0, (sum, r) => sum + r.men)
           let womenCount = g.Aggregate(0, (sum, r) => sum + r.women)
           let totalCount = menCount + womenCount
           select new { AgeGroup = g.Key, Men = menCount, Women = womenCount, Total = totalCount}
```

First I define a Function to return the AgeGroup for a given age(`(age / 5) * 5` gives the starting number for a AgeGroup). From there it’s pretty straightforward. Grouping the ages and add up the numbers.

**Edit:**
I don’t think it’s possible in one query. Because `group by` ends a query(like `select`) and you need to group first and then add up.
You can’t use `IQueryable`, because the `ageGroup()` Function is not know in SQL and therefore can’t be used in Linq2Sql.

Comment: thanks dear friend.how I can add a conditoin that only rows that `IsActive=1` calculated.Dear @Marcel Benthin in my reports in left side of above image I want to calculate `UnActive` rows.How I can merge this to query to one query?can use `IQuereable`?thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about using `group ... by`:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea#Simple1

http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2008/04/linq-group-by-syntax-for-grouping-on.html

Comment: Having in Linq 2 Sql is just another where clause.